# Exporting databases or tables can't be done in pl/sql developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am currently using PL/SQL developer software to manage my databases, however, when I want to import or export tables or databases, "Export" or "Import" buttons are disabled in it as shown in picture. Here, "Export" button can't be clicked as It is disabled. How can I solve this problem?
[Here is the screenshot of that problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kptwH.png)

Answer (score 4):

In order to be able to use those utilities, you have to install them onto the computer.

Depending on database version you use, there are two options: data pump export & import, or the *original* EXP and IMP utilities.

If you access the database which is not installed on your computer (which might be the case, regarding the fact that those buttons are disabled), you can

- install them as part of Oracle Client software, or
- a simpler option (from my point of view), install Oracle 11g Express Edition (which is a fully-operational, small-footprint database, but it installs all utilities you might need, including export & import, SQL*Loader, etc.)

Both are available in Oracle Technology Network's Download section; pick a version which suits you best. Note that old versions, which are out of support, can't be downloaded any more (but you can ask Oracle to provide them, if you have a valid license).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I have already installed Oracle 11g Express Edition.

Comment: OK, so you'd just have to "register" those utilities with PL/SQL Developer. I don't know, though, how to do it (I use TOAD).

Answer (score 2):

Littlefoot's answer is correct (i upvoted it).

I wanted also to point out that the three tabs you see in the screenshot you posted (tabs that I am highlighting in the attached image) represent three alternative methods you can use to export database data and structure.

[image: Please note the tabs I highlighted]

1. "Oracle Export" uses the official oracle tools you need to install on your client
2. "SQL Inserts" will produce plain SQL scripts (or a single script for all the tables) containing insert commands (and they will also contain the commands needed to re-create the tables, optionally)
3. "Pl/SQL Developer" will produce an export file in a proprietary format that can be understood only by PL/SQL Developer (you will need to have PL/SQL Developer to import such file"

   Options 2 and 3 do not require external tools.

Comment: Right; though, option #2 is doubtful if tables' size is *large*. I really wouldn't want to `INSERT INTO` millions and millions of rows, one by one. Other than that, yes, I agree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and Using other two options that you said helped me for exporting and importing